# android - issues with 2.2.1 emulators

Tags: android, emulation, developer-tools

Working with Android Development studio 2.2.1.  Have been working with the emulator and have experienced the following:

1. the Extended controls option for sending GPS data stopped working for my emulated device.  Had been working with my app receiving the correct GPS coordinated.
2. rotation of the screen failed to rotate the app's display.  Again this had been working with the app switching between landscape and portrait mode without a problem.

In an attempt to resolve/verify the issue was with the emulator, created a new emulated device.  The device I chose to emulate was a nexus 5.  What got generated was a device without any bezel that wouldn't respond to any of the extended control functions.

Finally, deleted emulated devices, rebooted and recreated my emulated devices.  Extended controls, screen rotation worked as expected on the new emulated devices.

Is there a better emulator from some other source.  Wasted way too much time tracking down a crappy intellij/android development issue.

Comment: Just deployed a emulated nexus 5x running 7.0 v x386 and the extended controls for setting location does not work.  No GPS coordinates are available.   Guess quality just doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: x86-64 also fails to send setting location to the emulated device.